# Translating a Perl reference to OO PHP?

Tags: php, perl, oop

So I tripped across another oddity in translating the old developers Perl script into
Object Orientated PHP, this little Perl reference statement has had me scratching my
head for quite a while, but I haven't been able to figure it out via Google or friends.

I've tried my best to write out what I believe it to mean, but am uncertain if it is
right. Could someone tell me if I figured it out or if I'm off? Thanks ahead of time.

The perl snippet is:

```
!$state->{$msg->{hash}}
```

I believe it means one of the two of these in OO PHP?

```
!$this->state[$this->msg['hash']] //or?
$this->state != $this->msg['hash']
```

Am I even in the ballpark?

**UPDATE** I was told this is a has reference, not an array reference, but I'm uncertain since $msg->{grey}, $msg->{hash}, $msg->{domain} etc all exist in the same sub?

Comment: We'll need a lot more context to answer this.  What is `$state`?  `Data::Dumper` is your friend.

Comment: Perl references are different to PHP references (aliases). I don't know if it's specifically possible to emulate perl references with PHP variables aliasing.

Comment: I believe that the closest we can come to it would be with using array() in php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, on a second glance, `$state` is a hash reference of some kind (although it could also be a `bless`ed object of some class), and `$state->{$msg->{hash}}` is the value of `%$state` corresponding to the key `$msg->{hash}` (which, in turn, is the value of `%$msg` that corresponds to the key `"hash"`).

So, assuming that `$state` and `$msg` are only hash references (and not specific objects), they actually correspond to arrays in PHP (one of the really dumb things about PHP is that there is no difference between an array and an associative array).

So, it would be `!$state[$msg['hash']]` in PHP.

Comment: Being bless'd doesn't change it from being a hashref. But the one thing that would change it from being an ordinary hashref would be if its tie'd. (Also, I'm going to fix your formatting—feel free to overwrite my edit if we collide)

Comment: Thanks Jack for taking the time to riddle it out.